# Purpose of Name before definition in C typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct Books
{
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
} Book;
```

I have come across the above example, where I can only define objects using Book and using Books gives unknown type. I understand that I can do without `Books` altogether, then what is the purpose of having it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*using Books gives unknown type*

***This is good***.  It suggests your compiler is one of recent design, following current trends in C programming.  As you have discovered, using the name Books is superfluous, and even generates warnings / errors. (compiler dependent)

Using the following syntax allows you to simply use Book to declare a new instance of the struct Book, (without having name Books) :

```
typedef struct
{
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
} Book;  

Book book, *pBook; //etc.
```

***And, it also tends*** to make code *a little less verbose*, i.e. having to write `struct Book` instead of just `Book` everytime we want to use it declaring a new instance, or using it in a function argument:

Answer (score 1):

You can leave out the first Book, like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
} Book;
```

But then that wouldn't work for linked lists, where the struct needs to be able to hold a pointer to itself:

```
struct List
{
    int data;
    struct List * next;  //  this line requires that List appear with 'struct'
};
```

The line `struct List *next;` needs to know there is a struct called `List` - this requires that `struct List` appear before that line.

If you leave out the second, then you would need to type `struct Book` instead of `Book` every time you wanted to use it in the rest of your program.  (Some consider that a feature, not a bug!)

(In C++, for reference, the first `Book` is sufficient and it is not necessary to use `struct` elsewhere and therefore the typedef is not useful.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `struct Books` as a type. It is shorthand for

```
struct Book_t
{
   //...
};

typedef struct Book_t Book;
```

Comment: then should I not be able to declare objects of type Book_t? As of now, I am unable to do it.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz - Yes, but using only `Book`, not `struct Book_t`.  He is suggesting that you can now use `Book` to declare new instances of struct Book_t.  eg. ***Book book, *pBook;*** creates an instance of `struct Book_t` and a pointer to `struct Book_t`

Answer (score 0):

The only type declared by your code is `struct Books`. A `typedef` never declares a type, but only creates a new name for another type. E.g

```
typedef int int0;
typedef int int1;
```

Creates two new names for `int` that are interchangeable with `int`, no new integer type is invented.

For type names that consist of several tokens, `typedef` is a convenient tool to abbreviate it to a one-token name

```
typedef unsinged long long int ullong;
typedef struct toto Toto;
```

The later one for `struct toto` has even the particularity to forward declare the `struct`, so you can then do

```
struct toto {
  Toto* next;
};
```

that is refer to `struct toto` inside its own definition.

The tag name space is distinct from the identifier namespace, so something as the following is even valid

```
typedef struct toto toto;
struct toto {
  toto* next;
};
```